# arrayWithArray:nil returns empty array but not documented

Tags: iphone, objective-c

NSArray and NSMutableArray's `+arrayWithArray:` returns empty array instead of nil when argument is nil.

```
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSArray arrayWithArray:nil] class]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:nil] class]);
```

output:

```
    __NSArrayI
    __NSArrayM
```

But this behavior is not documented on Apples documentation.

Is it safe to rely on the assumption that `arrayWithArray:nil` returns empty array?
Or should I assign empty array explicitly like this:

```
    NSDictionary *dic = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *arr = [dic objectForKey:@"a"];
    if (!arr) {
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation of `+arrayWithArray:` says:

> Creates and returns an array containing the objects in another given
>   array.

Of course, `nil` is not an array, but `[nil count]` is valid and returns `0`, so it might be treated as an empty array here.

**But I would not rely on that fact** and create empty arrays with `[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` or `[NSMutableArray array]`.

**ADDED:**

If you call `+arrayWithArray:` with an invalid type, e.g. a `NSString`, then of course the program will throw an exception. But from the error message

```
-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x69e4
```

you can see that `count` is indeed the first method used to copy the array elements. That also explains why it works with `nil`.

Comment: You'll find this has since been updated with nullability info (largely for Swift), and the compiler / static analyzer will now complain about a nil argument.